# build sctp protocol ss7 openss7

Tags: protocols, sctp

I try to make an ss7 application using openss7 and sctp.
 I made some simple application using SCTP. the part of the source code is like below :

```
    sock_srvr = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_SCTP);
    if ( sock_srvr == -1 ) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(0);    
    }
```

and it return

```
socket: Protocol not supported
```

do you have any suggestion ?. 
Is there anyone who have experience with openss7 before ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using linux:

1. Ensure CONFIG_IP_SCTP=m or CONFIG_IP_SCTP=y in kernel config
2. It is a good idea to install http://lksctp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1):

Which OS is this? SCTP is not natively supported on various OS. Only latest versions of Solaris support SCTP out of box. In linux, you might have to install a package.

In addition, your socket system call is wrong.

```
sock_srvr = socket(PF_INET, **SOCK_STREAM**, IPPROTO_SCTP);
```

SCTP is a stream based protocol just like TCP.